# Raw resource file type

Tags: android, android-resources

How do you detect what kind of file the resource is? In my case there could be videos and images.

So in case it's a video, I use a `VideoView`; and in the case of an image, I use an `ImageView`?

I'm getting the resource id like this:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(resourceID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's impossible *without* reading/ analyzing the binary data of files (like [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html)). The easiest way is to prefix file names with predefined strings. For example:

- `video_file_00`, `video_file_01`…
- `image_file_00`, `image_file_01`…

Then you can use [`getResourceName(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceName%28int%29) to parse the file names.

Comment: Yes, this is the most simple way. Thanks, this will work the best I think

Answer (score 1):

the only thing I have in mind is that you can check the file names using constants like this:

```
 final String type = getApplicationContext().getResources().getResourceTypeName(resID);
 if(type.equals("drawable")){
   // handle it like an image
 }else if(.....) //do some research for other constants
```

Comment: How would I get the filename? Im just have the resource id